# Jekyll multiple Permalinks support

Tags: jekyll, permalinks, github-pages

Does Jekyll support setting multiple permalinks?

For example, I currently have the following in my `_config.yml`:

`permalink:   /:categories/:title/`

What I would like to have, is the following:

`permalink:
- /:categories/:title/
- /:year/:month/:day/:title/`

What I'm trying to achieve it that a single post will have multiple URLs. I'm well aware that I can use the "redirect_from" plugin (I'm hosting in GitHub Pages), but that would require me to manually update all my posts to include the `redirect_from` in the YAML

Comment: The developers want to have a 1:1 relationship as you can see here: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/3368 Maybe that will change, if many people vote for the ticket.

Answer (score 2):

have you checked out jekyll-archives? https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-archives

you can create other permalinks like

```
permalinks:
  year: '/:year/'
  month: '/:year/:month/'
  day: '/:year/:month/:day/'
  tag: '/tag/:name/'
  category: '/category/:name/'
```

i don't think you can use :title though. it's an index page that lists posts.